# error in theta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I have this question that I am not sure how to finish. I started computing it, but I just couldn`t finish it.

> Assume the following first ODE
>
> > $y'=f(x,y)$        for $x\in[a,b]$         with $y(x_0)=y_0$
>
> has a unique solution.

Noting that the function $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with respect to the second variable $y$ with Lipschitz constant $L$.
Recall that, the approximate solution $y_{n+1}$ of $y(x_{n+1})$ obtained using $\theta$-method for the above equation where $\theta \in [0,1]$ , is defined by:
$$ y_{n+1} = y_n + h[(1-\theta) f(x_n , y_n) +\theta f(x_{n+1}, y_{n+1})] , n=0,1,...,N-1$$
$y_0$ is given , where $h=\frac{b-a}{h}$ and $x_n=a+nh$ for $n=1,...,N$

the question is :

> let $e_n=y(x_n)-y_n$. For smooth $y$ show that $$  {e_n} \le Ch( \vert{\frac{1}{2}-\theta}\vert + h)$$

please any help would be appreciated. I tried to use Taylor's expansion, but I'm not sure what did I do wrong.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1486008/115115 about the local error and apply the usual method to connect the local to the global error. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213614/115115 for numerical order estimates for these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Taylor we know that
$$
y(x+θh)=y(x)+y'(x)θh+\tfrac12y''(x)(θh)^2+O(h^3)
$$
and
$$
y(x+θh)=y(x+h)-y'(x+h)(1-θ)h+\tfrac12y''(x+h)((1-θ)h)^2+O(h^3)
$$
so that in the difference
\begin{align}
y(x+h)-y(x) &= \begin{aligned}[t]
&\bigl[θy'(x)+(1-θ)y'(x+h)\bigr]h \\&- \tfrac12\bigl[(1-θ)^2y''(x+h)-θ^2y''(x)\bigr]h^2\\&+O(h^3)
\end{aligned}
\\
&=\begin{aligned}[t]
&\bigl[θf(x,y(x))+(1-θ)f(x+h,y(x+h))\bigr]h \\&- \tfrac12(1-2θ)y''(x+\tilde θh)h^2\\&+O(h^3)
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
Now compare this to
$$
y_{n+1}-y_n=\bigl[θf(x_n,y_n)+(1-θ)f(x_n+h,y_{n+1})\bigr]h
$$
to get
$$
e_{n+1}-e_n=\begin{aligned}[t]
&[θ\partial_yf(x_n,y(x_n))e_n+(1-θ)\partial_yf(x_{n+1},y(x_{n+1}))e_{n+1}]h\\& - (\tfrac12-θ)y''(x+\tilde θh)h^2\\&+O(h^3,he_n^2,he_{n+1}^2)
\end{aligned}
$$
Now solve this recursion. If $L$ is a bound for $ \partial_yf$ and $M_2$ a bound of $y''$, then
$$
(1-(1-θ)Lh)|e_{n+1}|\le (1+θLh)|e_n|+|\tfrac12-θ|M_2h^2+M_3h^3 
\\
|e_{n+1}|\le e^{Lh+(\tfrac12-θ)h^2+ h^3 }|e_n|+e^{(1-θ)Lh+h^2}(|\tfrac12-θ|M_2h^2+M_3h^3)
$$
which indeed has a result like
$$
e_n\le Ch\frac{e^{L(nh)}-1}{L}(|\tfrac12-θ|+h)
$$
where the higher order term are absorbed into the constant $C$, which is about $C=\max(M_2,M_3)+1$.