# Bound on truncation error for theta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Let $x(t)$ be the solution to a differential equation:
$$
x'(t) = f(t, x(t))
$$
where $f:[t_0, T] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a $C^1$ function.

We consider the problem of approximating $x$ using a partition $t_i = t_0 + ih$ for $i = 0 \dots N$ using the $\theta$-method succession $${x_{i+1}} = x_i + h ((1-\theta) f(t_i, x_i) + \theta f(t_{i+1}, x_{i+1}))$$

I want to prove that the truncation error:
$$ \tau(h) = \max_t \left( \frac{x(t + h) - x(t)}{h} - ((1-\theta) x'(t) + \theta x'(t+h) \right)$$
can be bound by:
$$ \tau(h) \leq \tfrac{1}{2} cMh$$
where $M = \max_{t \in [t_0, T]} ||x''||_{\infty}$ and $c$ satisfies $||x|| \leq c ||x||_{\infty}$ for all $x$.

**What I have tried**
I have been able to prove the weaker bound:
$$ \tau(h) \leq  (\frac{1}{2} + \theta)cMh$$
using the Taylor expansion. We can write:
$$x(t + h) = x(t) + hx'(t) + \frac{h^2}{2} x''(\xi)$$
and
$$x'(t + h) = x'(t) + hx''(\eta)$$
for some $\xi, \eta \in (t, t+h)$.

This implies:
$$
||\tau(h)|| = h \left| \left| \frac{1}{2} x''(\xi) -  \theta x''(\eta) \right| \right|
$$
and we can find the previous bound by bounding:
$$
\left| \left| \frac{1}{2} x''(\xi) -  \theta x''(\eta) \right| \right| \leq (\frac{1}{2} + \theta) cM
$$

Comment: See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381289/error-in-theta-method, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213614/numerical-estimates-for-the-convergence-order-of-trapezoidal-like-runge-kutta-me

Comment: @LutzLehmann I looked at both before posting. If I am not wrong, both of them assume stronger regularity conditions ($C^2$) on $f$, so they are not applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

Following the cited post, a more convenient midpoint is $t+(1-\theta)h$ so that
\begin{align}
x(t+(1−θ)h)&=x(t)+(1−θ)hx'(t)+\frac{(1−θ)^2h^2}2x''(\xi_1)\\
&=x(t+h)-θhx'(t+h)+\frac{θ^2h^2}2x''(\xi_2)
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
\tau(t,h)&=\frac{h}2(θ^2x''(\xi_2)-(1−θ)^2x''(\xi_1))\\
\tau(h)&\le\frac{Mh}4(1+(1-2θ)^2)
\end{align}
and the last factor is at worst $2$.